# Low CPU/Memory/Memory-bandwith Pathfinding (maybe like in Warcraft 1)

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

Dijkstra and A* are all nice and popular but what kind of algorithm was used in Warcraft 1 for pathfinding?

I remember that the enemy could get trapped in bowl-like caverns which means there were (most probably) no full-path calculations from "start to end".
If I recall correctly, the algorithm could be something like this:

A) Move towards enemy until success or hitting a wall

B) If blocked by a wall, follow the wall until you can move towards the enemy without being blocked and then do A)

But I'd like to know, if someone knows :-)

[edit] As explained to Byte56, I'm searching for a low cpu/mem/mem-bandwidth algo and wanted to know if Warcraft had some special secrets to deliver (never seen that kind of pathfinding elsewhere), I hope that that is more concordant with the stackexchange rules.

Comment: A wall? You mean a static blocking entity? I don't see how a unit could hit a static entity since the pathfinding calculations surely take the current graph (with static blocking entities) in account. I don't think it calculates the path from start to end but i think the graph is subdivided into smaller graphs. I played a lot of warcraft1 and i think it's a basic A* with recalculations when a unit hit another dynamic unit... but i'm not sure. Starcraft 1 use A* algorithm.

Comment: I don't think it used A* at all.  A 33MHz CPU doing all the raster and in-game calculations?  There was probably no room to do any kind of intelligent pathfinding at all.

Comment: @nathan: In the question I'm only talking about the static walls. I guess the dynamic entities just updates the "block-map" as they spawn, move or die :-) so that shouldn't change anything if it Isn't A* or similar.

Comment: @bobobobo : I think you're right ant incidentally that's why I'd like to know :-)

Comment: I don't see how this is more than just trivia. Can you explain how it's useful?

Comment: Check this: http://www.codeofhonor.com/blog/tough-times-on-the-road-to-starcraft

Comment: @Byte56 I'm searching a pathfinding algo that doesn't use neither a lot of cpu nor a lot of memory (especially memory bandwidth) and this seems to be it.

Comment: @Valmond Then you should ask for one. Don't ask how a specific game does `A`, ask how you can do `A`. You're bound to get better answers and it wouldn't be off topic (like this question is).

Comment: You are right, just edited.

Comment: If you're looking for a "low cpu/mem/mem-bandwidth algo", see [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/32831/2061), which will give much better results than the crappy algorithm used by Warcraft 1.  The reason it wasn't used by WC1 was that it hadn't been invented yet.  Look also into Theta*, a relatively new *(2007)* and extremely simple variant of A* that allows units to move at any-angle, not just along grid-points *(it's simpler, faster, and gives better results than path-smoothing)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Hmm, it's like an oct-tree A* ? Nice and so but still A* and probably no longer optimal (Only a  guess though because of the space partitioning). If you got a small space you might calculate All paths in polynomial time so if you don't change the topology that would be even faster... Thanks though and I'll check out the HP-A* algo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually this turned out to be a more interesting question than I thought.

[Video](http://youtu.be/fbfaBJ4nOBI)

I forgot about the "right hand rule" for pathfinding, but it appears that the game uses it.

Say you're lost in a basement and it's dark.  The easiest way to find an exit (if there is one!) is to place your hand on the nearest wall and "follow the wall", following all it's turns and going through it's crevices, until you find an exit.  The only time this doesn't work is if you happen to grab a pole ("island") in the basement, then you'll be walking around that pole forever.

I think the game uses some variation of this "follow the wall" rule until the unit can find a beeline to the destination point.

[image]

Comment: From the video you linked, it looked like the orc followed the wall until it got back to the original blocked line.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it! I jumped the gun on beelining.

Comment: Very nice video +1 thanks for that! Your image (images and videos should get at least +2 at vote-up!) seems, for me at least, to be like the pseudo-algorithm I described in the original post, right?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think "how did X game accomplish Y?" is technically in the scope of this stack, but I'll hazard a guess as to why some pathfinding algorithms get stuck in a bowl: They run something like A*, but only up to a certain depth. This limits the amount of processing time spent pathfinding, but doesn't guarantee exhaustive search [which might be a good thing, Starcraft had that issue where dragoons would wander to the other side of the map trying to find a path]

[image: Illustration of two orcs navigating bowl-shaped walls]

In the top scenario, the top orc's search radius is too small. The "best" visible point is marked A, the "best" navigable point is on the closer side of the wall across from A.

In the bottom scenario, point A is now navigable, but point B should be the "best" navigable point, and that would be the path a constrained A* would take.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I doubt A* was used, you can get Dijkstra to run much faster in small 'maps' if you got direct memory access (ie. C/C++ / asm).

Comment: thanks for the edit but I think the algo works as I explained, otherwise the orc wouldn't move along the wall (and for my example to 'fail' then the bowl have to be rounder, like a circle with a small opening in it, your example would work I think). I'd love to know for sure though :-)