# Further improvement on algorithm A *

Tags: c++

i have a game use A*, this algorithm find path is good in many case.

But if I could not find the way to the destination, it would have to go through many nodes (my map is in gird format). I am looking for an algorithm to know that if I cannot find the way to the destination, A * algorithm will not work to avoid wasting CPU or then my object will only go straight to the target, when it collision with an object, it will stop. I saw a game like Age of Empires, when the farmer was locked in between the 4 walls, which meant he couldn't go out. If I want him to go to a point outside those four walls, he just goes straight to that point and stops when he hits a wall. If the 4 walls have a hole, he will go there and get there[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SV8I.png)
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5s5f.png)

Thanks everyone !

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47042/how-to-determine-that-nodes-in-grid-graph-are-unreachable-before-applying-pathfi/47043 Take your starting map. Pick a node. Fill out from this node. All filled nodes are reachable from this first node (and vice versa, assuming you can't jump down ledges and things like that). Pick a new node not in the set of reachable nodes you just found. Repeat. At the end you have M buckets, each with the set of co-reachable nodes. Update this whenever the map updates.

Comment: In order to find that closest point inside the reachable space, it's still running an A* query within that reachable space. You just accept the node with the best heuristic result you've seen if you've exhausted the reachable nodes to check.

Comment: Oh, thanks DMGregory,  i think it is good idea !